# Popover in the navigation bar results in broken animation

Tags: swiftui

When I have a `popover` in the navigation bar the animation is broken when closing the `popover`. Also it can only be opened once. It works fine on the iPad, but the animation is different on the iPad. Is this a bug?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showPopover:Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Text("Popover Animation Test")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Popover") { self.showPopover = true }
            .popover(isPresented: self.$showPopover) { Text("Hello from Popover") })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect? Looks like a bug... I would use .popover for iPad and .sheet for iPhone if needs both, or only sheet for iPhone-only case.